# pandas - Increase datetime hour(More information is in the article.)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I pulled out one column from the data frame and added it to a variable named timestamp.

```
0    2017-01-10 04:45:00
1    2017-01-10 04:45:00
2    2017-01-10 04:45:00
3    2017-01-10 04:46:00
4    2017-01-10 04:46:00
5    2017-01-10 04:46:00
6    2017-01-10 04:47:00
7    2017-01-10 04:47:00
8    2017-01-10 17:47:00
9    2017-01-10 17:52:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

The type of data is:

```
type(timestamp)

Out[1]: pandas.core.series.Series

type(timestamp.values)

Out[1]: numpy.ndarray
```

What I want to do is add 9 hours.

```
0    2017-01-10 13:45:00
1    2017-01-10 13:45:00
2    2017-01-10 13:45:00
3    2017-01-10 13:46:00
4    2017-01-10 13:46:00
5    2017-01-10 13:46:00
6    2017-01-10 13:47:00
7    2017-01-10 13:47:00
8    2017-01-11 02:47:00
9    2017-01-11 02:52:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me what I should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#time-deltas):

```
 s1 + pd.Timedelta(hours=9)
```

Output:

```
0   2017-01-10 13:45:00
1   2017-01-10 13:45:00
2   2017-01-10 13:45:00
3   2017-01-10 13:46:00
4   2017-01-10 13:46:00
5   2017-01-10 13:46:00
6   2017-01-10 13:47:00
7   2017-01-10 13:47:00
8   2017-01-11 02:47:00
9   2017-01-11 02:52:00
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I got this error.
TypeError: must be str, not Timedelta
What type should I change?

Comment: Ah.. Your original series is not a pandas datetime.   It is a datetime module datetime.  You could pd.to_datetime(timestamp).

Comment: Thank you. I did not get an error because of this, but the time does not change./

a = pd.to_datetime(timestamp)\n
a = a + pd.Timedelta(hours=9)\n
a

Comment: That's odd.  a = a + pd.Timedelta(hours=9) didn't advance a nine hours?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I was wrong. Thank you for letting us know.